# Reference undefined property

Tags: c#

So I have a pretty simple question.  I have a function that receives 2 parameters.  Here is the function definition:

```
 private void Document_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I know that the sender object will always have a property called text, but the compiler obviously doesn't know this.  Is there a good way for me to reference this property without getting compiler errors?  Obviously sender.property doesn't work.

Comment: What is document? What Type?

Comment: Cast the sender to the correct type. Say u know the event was fired by a button u can just do : `((Button)sender).Text`

Comment: Document is a text box from a windows form. Defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a cast. If you're always sure that sender is of type SomeType, you can simply use

```
SomeType senderAsSomeType = (SomeType)sender;
```

If you cannot be sure what the type is, you can use the `as` operator to cast the value if it is of type SomeType, or get `null` if it is not:

```
SomeType senderAsSomeType = sender as SomeType;
if (senderAsSomeType != null) {
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

another option is to use dynamic if there is a chance for few classes with the text property like this :

```
dynamic textProperty = sender;
Console.WriteLine(textProperty.Text);
```

Comment: This is a fun method and can save some characters. However, duck typing in c# is a flaky practice. If you want an object to participate in a foreign system, there really should be a common interface - in this case, _Control_. This way, you get compile time errors, not runtime, if anything changes during the project lifetime.

Comment: Further, dynamic is intended for interop with dynamic environments. COM and DOM being the prime offenders. Outside of that you may never need it.